# Grocery Store Micromanagement

Tags: code-golf, string, grid

You are an employee at the hip new grocery store Half Foods, and it's the day before <s>Thanksgiving</s> <s>Christmas</s> Easter. Since the store will be packed with customers rushing to get their foodstuffs, the store needs a traffic manager to send everyone to the appropriate lines. Being lazy, you'd like to automate this so that you can go hit the deli before everyone takes all the <s>turkey</s> <s>ham</s> whatever. However, all you have with you is your phone, and coding long programs on it is a real pain -- so you need to bust out your ninja [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) skills.

### Challenge

Let's visualize the grocery store on a two-dimensional grid. Here's a sample grid to dissect:

```
                             e
                             s
                             s
                             s
                               Y

#           #                #s           #
#s          #                #s           #
#s          #                #s           #
#s          #s               #s           #
#3          #1               #4           #
 x           x                x            x
```

The grid starts out with an `e`, which represents an "outlet" to the rest of the store. Every generation, all of the outlets in the grid spawn a shopper (`s`) directly below. The shoppers move downward each generation until they reach you (`Y`). When a shopper reaches the same row as you, you must teleport the shopper to the beginning of the line with the least amount of shoppers in it. A shopper immediately moves to the line when they would move into the row with the `Y`, there is no generation in between. The lines are represented by the `#`s -- the column after the `#`s is a line. The shoppers go down to the end of the line (represented by an exit `x`), and then turn into a random number between `1` and `5`. Each generation, you must decrement numbered shoppers by `1` -- when a shopper would reach `0`, they're done checking out and they leave the store.

Given an input of a grid like this, output the next generation of the grocery store (move all the shoppers down simultaneously, redirect shoppers, and have them leave if they are done).

### Samples

Input:

```
                e
                 
                     Y


#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
 x           x                x            x
```

Output:

```
                e
                s 
                     Y


#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
 x           x                x            x
```

Input:

```
                e
                s 
                     Y


#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
 x           x                x            x
```

Output

```
                e
                s 
                     Y


#s          #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
 x           x                x            x
```

Input:

```
                e
                 
                     Y


#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#s          #                #            #
#           #                #            #
 x           x                x            x
```

(Possible) Output:

```
                e
                s 
                     Y


#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#3          #                #            #
 x           x                x            x
```

Input:

```
                e
                s 
                     Y


#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#3          #                #            #
 x           x                x            x
```

Output:

```
                e
                s 
                     Y


#           #s               #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#2          #                #            #
 x           x                x            x
```

Input:

```
                e
                 
                     Y


#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#1          #                #            #
 x           x                x            x
```

Output:

```
                e
                s 
                     Y


#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
#           #                #            #
 x           x                x            x
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

Comment: I really don't get the input format.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Input can be either a multi-line string or an array of single line strings as per our defaults for taking multiple lines of input.

Comment: No, I mean that I just don't get the challenge, really.

Comment: Rather than rely on the examples, it might be worth stating explicitly that the shopper can never be on the same row as Y, as moving down to the Y row and being teleported to the top of the relevant queue happen in a single step.

Comment: It would also help to have a description of how a queue moves, with a test case as an example. If there are 3 shoppers vertically adjacent in a queue, and the lowest can move down, do all 3 move down together in a single step or does the available space move up one row at a time as each shopper moves into it?

Comment: This sounds fun. Will the lines (#s) always be the same length as each other? Should shoppers always be sent to the queue with the least people? E.g. 5sss is likely slower than 1ssss, by 1 generation on average. Or is the point to simulate the uncertainty of this situation in real life? :)

Comment: @ChrisM Very belated but yes they'll be the same length. I didn't want to overcomplicate the line selection procedure even though there's a chance shorter lines could be slower.

Comment: Do we assume that there will always be 4 lines of #, and, if yes, do we assume that the array are always at the same position ? Also, do we assume that the input will the result of a previous generation ?

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun There can be an arbitrary number of lines. I can add examples with more lines if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>477</s> <s>463</s> <s>453</s> <s>449</s> <s>423</s> <s>402</s> <s>397</s> <s>396</s> 393 bytes

```python
t=input()
e=enumerate
q,r=" s"
for i,L in list(e(t))[:0:-1]:
 for j,c in e(L):
	a=t[i-1][j]
	if"0"<c<"6":L[j]="0 1234"[int(c)]
	if(r==a)*q==L[j]:t[i-1][j],L[j]=q+r
	if"e"==a:L[j]=r
	if r==L[j]and"x"==t[i+1][j]:L[j]="5"
 if"Y"in L:x=L.count(r);t[i]=[p.replace(r,q)for p in L]
for i,l in list(e(t))[::-1]:
 for j,c in e(l):
	if"#"==c and(q==l[j+1])*x:x-=1;l[j+1]=r
print"\n".join(map("".join,t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZJNbsIwEIXX5BTWsMAGEwH9WRh8g1wAuVlEqVEdBScxRkpPn04S1EUFElEDm5Ht98bzPcvlt/8q7KZpvDS2PHvKAi21PR@1S7wOKu4kkBMEh8IRwyNiLMnNyVNNPWNKrMRyHYuAtHLG01bWNGIimCTSK4OiyuJgYg6wgl26g3cQEZ5IWJH15uUVlLGepqyzUCdlwuaVlK1F/LbzrqNauO4eDejqL@kOiOv9if2EGjVsW3Rtl0FvEBBs2wOiRaKWUZgWZxzq2BatsVRl6HSZJ6mmjlesDVK2MaL4kjn/m/la5LyNjGOmSJASZKEYI1cZorB5LeqlXG/7LVKXDlPDh4UwK4ylx6Sk0K85DmgapWZkxsndRQ8WhpdwFnMykOt0ZXVt@2yuf5f9mFzTWy8yfQT6WFxjAz/yvZ7Itb4lbIYkGf/f1@MJ93DF8Q8)

Still working on golfing this but it solves the problem for now

Comment: You can remove excess indentation and line breaks (single line blocks can go on the same line as the start of the block)

Comment: @SolomonUcko Where are you talking about?

Comment: 1. Are tabs 8 spaces to python? 2. I think you can remove the line breaks after the last 2 for loops.

Comment: 1. Tabs are their own thing in Python. 2. You can't remove that line break.

Comment: 1. Does python just count the first indentation level in a block as the indentation level for that block? 2. Do you know _why_ not? I tested it and it doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, wow about the program.

Comment: I've updated to spec to clarify this, but the "when a shopper reaches 0 they leave" means that when a shopper *would* reach 0 they leave, not the generation after they hit 0. (That is if you have a shopper at 1 they will be gone next generation). The last example illustrates this.

Comment: Other than that this seems great. I originally hadn't considered multiple entrances but since your program supports it I'll update the spec to specify there can be multiple.

Comment: @quartata Cool I fixed the problem.  Unfortunately it didn't save any bytes to remove zero.  But on the bright side it didn't cost any either.

Comment: how did you get a bounty from the community?

Comment: @tfbninja There was a bounty that expired and I had the top voted new answer so I received half of it.

Answer (score 4):

### C++, <s>898</s> <s>896</s> <s>885</s> 841 bytes

Very long to code... but it's there

-2 bytes thanks to Conor O'Brien
-45 byte thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<ctime>
#define B begin()
#define L length()
#define C(e)if(i[j].find(e)!=string::npos&&!
#define S's'
#define T size()
#define U i[x][a]
using namespace std;auto g=[](auto&i){int e=i[0].find('e'),n=0,y=0,h=0,o,j,c,x,t=0;for(auto&a:i)t=a.L>t?a.L:t;for_each(i.B,i.end(),[&i,t](string&s){s.resize(t);});srand(time(0));vector<int>s,l;for(j=0;j<i.T;++j){C(S)y)++n;C(89)0)y=j;C(35)h){h=j;for(int d=0;d<i[j].T;++d)if(i[j][d]==35)l.push_back(d+1);s.resize(l.T);}if(h)for(c=0;c<l.T;c++)if(i[j][l[c]]!=32)++s[c];C('x')0)x=j;}--x;for_each(l.B,l.end(),[&i,&x,h](int&a){if(U!=32)--U;if(U==10)U=32;for(int b=x;b>h;--b){if(i[b][a]==32&&i[b-1][a]==S){i[b][a]=S;i[b-1][a]=32;}}if(U==S)U=49+rand()%5;});if(i[y-1][e]==S)i[h][l[min_element(s.B,s.end())-s.B]]=S;for(j=1;j<n+2;++j)if(j<y)i[j][e]=S;};
```

So... some details :

- You have to pass a `std::vector<std::string>` ( they will be resized at the same length the longest string is )
- All lines of `#` starts at the same y ( vertical ) coordinates, are the same length, and end at the same y ( vertical ) coordinates
- Assume that the grid have at least 1 `#` line or more, have one letter `e` ( one outlet ) at the top, one letter `Y`
- Assume that the input is a valid output so the shoppers waiting to be redirected will always be one after another

Edit : Just saw in the comments of Wheat Wizard's answer that it should support multiple entrances, i will continue to work on that

Comment: Maybe you could make that C macro be `#define C(e)i[j].find(e)!=string::npos`?

Comment: My answer supports multiple entrances as a side effect, of it being golfy.  Quartata said it would be required, but I don't see it in the question, so as far as I'm concerned you are free to only support a single entrance.

Comment: @WheatWizard Well, if i read the question, it says : "The grid starts out with an e, which represents an outlet" and "all of the outlets", so that suggest it can have several entrances

Comment: You can change the definition of `C(e)` to be `#define C(e)if(i[j].find(e)!=string::npos` and change the calls accordingly.

Comment: And since `length()` is only applied on `a`, you can change `L` to be defined as `a.length()`, modifying calls accordingly. In addition, you can move the `using namespace std;` to the bottom, saving a byte by removing the newline

Comment: Three things, `using namespace std;` can be placed on the bottom line to save a byte, and you can remove the space between `C(e)` and its definition, and all that combined with a ton macro-shenanigans gives [841 bytes](https://pastebin.com/shM2U7D0)

Comment: 840 bytes, using `#define T.size()` and replacing the references accordingly (which means changing every `.` before `T` to a space except for `i[j].T` which becomes `i[j]T`, saving the byte)

Comment: [734 bytes](https://ideone.com/yb3ck8)